# Getting DownValues from memoized function - ParallelEvaluate only uses one kernel at a time

Tags: parallelization, memoization, downvalues

I have the following code where I calculate primorial(n) using a memoized function. When I run this function in ParallelDo everything is fine - the calculation runs on 8 kernels.

But I want to use these values down the road - so I grab the Downvalues using ParallelEvaluate - but I observe that it does this on each parallel kernel sequentially - and thus takes about as long to get the DownValues as it does to calculate the primorials in the first place. I thought this would just be a very quick process.

Shouldn't this also run all eight kernels in parallel?

What am I not understanding or missing here?

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];

LaunchKernels[];

kernels = ParallelEvaluate[$KernelID];

num = 20000;

primorial[n_] := primorial[n] = Fold[Times, 1, Prime[Range[n]]];

ParallelDo[primorial[i], {i, 1, num}, ProgressReporting -> True, 
    Method -> Automatic]; // AbsoluteTiming // First

DownValues[primorial] = 
    DeleteDuplicates[
     Flatten[ParallelEvaluate[DownValues[primorial], kernels]]]; // 
  AbsoluteTiming // First

CloseKernels[];
```

Comment: Why to calculate `primorial[n]` using  `Fold[Times, 1, Prime[Range[n]]]` for $n$ if you already have calculated `primorial[n-1]`? It seems you are calculating the same many times.  I suggest a recursive definition `primorialR[0] = 1;primorialR[n_] := primorialR[n] = Prime[n]*primorialR[n - 1];`

Comment: Sure, you will run out of memory if you have memoized definition with 10K entries.  `primorial[n] = Fold[Times, 1, Prime[Range[n]]]` is a memory-efficient definition, but you are forcing the kernel to memorize it for all the values anyways when you evaluate `primorial[i]` for `{i, 1, num}`. This looks like a XY problem. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Why would I run out of memory for 10K entries? I already know that doesn't happen with the code I posted. My problem is the DownValues call with ParallelEvaluate seemingly being sequential.

Comment: To repost my deleted comment - MMa can't build large recursive structures without memory problems but it can memoize a lot of function values. That is why I went the way I did.